# How can I have sparql data in a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, sparql

On this website https://dbpedia.org/sparql I have this query

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
SELECT ?label ?lat ?long WHERE {  

<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sargus_Juvenile_Detention_Center> geo:lat ?lat.
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sargus_Juvenile_Detention_Center> geo:long ?long.
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sargus_Juvenile_Detention_Center> rdfs:label ?label . }
```

The ouput is

```
label                                        lat           long
"Sargus Juvenile Detention Center"@en        40.0767       -80.9656
```

How can I run this query in python and save it to a dataframe?

Comment: you can get the output as CSV via Accept Header `text/csv` and then load the CSV into a dataframe - that's it

Answer (score 0):

You could use the sparql-dataframe library
https://pypi.org/project/sparql-dataframe/

```
import pandas as pd
import sparql_dataframe

endpoint = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql"

q = """
    PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
    SELECT ?label ?lat ?long WHERE {  
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sargus_Juvenile_Detention_Center> geo:lat ?lat.
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sargus_Juvenile_Detention_Center> geo:long ?long.
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Sargus_Juvenile_Detention_Center> rdfs:label ?label . }
    """

df = sparql_dataframe.get(endpoint, q)
df.head()
```

Output:

```
    label   lat     long
0   Sargus Juvenile Detention Center    40.0767     -80.9656
```

Dataframe info:

```
df.info()
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   label   1 non-null      object 
 1   lat     1 non-null      float64
 2   long    1 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 152.0+ bytes
```